# What constitutes a programming language dialect?

Tags: programming-languages

Usually I see the term *dialect* for programming languages referring to small variations of a language, such as slightly different syntax or supported features in BASIC, SQL, or Lisp.

I have also seen in the context of R that the "Tidyverse" set of packages form their own "universe" or "dialect" that is based on some common ideas, such as function composition in the form of piping, and so-called "tidy evaluation" framework using quasi-quotation, "quosures", and "data masks". This is all implemented in R with metaprogramming, though the end-user usually does not need to know the details of how it works. The resulting tidyverse code uses significantly different syntax than base R style code.

In fact, when I use R, tidyverse libraries are so widespread that one way to categorize any library I use is whether it's "tidyverse/ggplot2" or "base R" style. The tidyverse implements libraries that supplant almost all functionality of base R. There is something on a smaller scale for the popular "data.table" package. There is also something vaguely similar in Python where many scientific libraries make use of numpy arrays as a common type.

Given this, does the tidyverse form a "dialect" of R? Is there a widely-accepted definition for programming language dialect?

Comment: I don't know what kind of answer you expect.  The answer will presumably depend on what you mean by "dialect", and I don't know if there's an accepted agreement on the meaning of that word to the level that would make the answer to this question clearcut.   I suspect this question tells us more about how the respondent interprets the word "dialect" than any fundamental truth about R.  In other words, this basically seems like a matter of opinion to me.  Perhaps others will have a different perspective.

Comment: An answer could be "there is no agreed upon definition of dialect specific enough" which would answer the question

Comment: Note that in linguistics (i.e. the people concerned with human languages as opposed to computer languages), there is a general consensus that the distinction between language and dialect is largely subjective and political in nature, not scientific. "A language is a dialect with an Army and a Navy."